# OLAP Cubes - When dimension has been read/accessed last time

Tags: mdx, olap, cubes

Is there any way to see when OLAP cube dimension has been read accessed last time ?
Is that information held anywhere ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such information are held in the DMVs. 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017][1]

Now i am not sure there is a dmv which tells when the last read was(try exploring diffrent dmv). Incase there is no such dmv,the following dmv can help.It tells how many times an object was read. You could preoidcally log its result to achive the results

```
select * from $System.DISCOVER_OBJECT_ACTIVITY
```